# WebSocket won't reconnect after dropped internet

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using graphql-ws https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-ws to manage my websocket connection, but am unable to figure out how to handle a dropped connection. Once my internet drops (toggling wifi) or computer sleeps, subscriptions all drop and websocket never reconnects.

`closed` never gets called. Everything else works as expected, just the disconnects an issue.

```
        createClient({
          retryAttempts: 5,
          shouldRetry: () => true,
          url: "ws://localhost:8080",
          on: {
            connected: () => {
              console.log("CONNECTED");
            },
            closed: () => {
              console.log("CLOSED");
            },
            error: (e) => {
              console.log(e);
            },
          },
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keepAlive`, ping, and pong as a trigger to restart your connection, and keep `retryAttempt` to infinite.
That's my attempt at keeping the socket alive:

```js
createClient({
    url: 'wss://$domain/v1/graphql',
    retryAttempts: Infinity,
    shouldRetry: () => true,
    keepAlive: 10000,
    connectionParams: () => {
        const access_token = getAccessTokenFunction();
        return {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token || ''}`
            }
        };
    },
    on: {
        connected: (socket) => {
            activeSocket = socket; // to be used at pings & pongs
            // get the access token expiry time and set a timer to close the socket
            // once the token expires... Since 'retryAttempts: Infinity' it will
            // try to reconnect again by getting a fresh token.
            const token_expiry_time = getTokenExpiryDate();
            const current_time = Math?.round(+new Date() / 1000);
            const difference_time = (token_expiry_time - current_time) * 1000;
            if (difference_time > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (socket?.readyState === WebSocket?.OPEN) {
                        socket?.close(CloseCode?.Forbidden, "Forbidden");
                    }
                }, difference_time);
            }
        },
        ping: (received) => {
            if (!received)
                // sent
                timedOut = setTimeout(() => {
                    if (activeSocket?.readyState === WebSocket?.OPEN)
                        activeSocket?.close(4408, 'Request Timeout');
                }, 5000); // wait 5 seconds for the pong and then close the connection
        },
        pong: (received) => {
            if (received) clearTimeout(timedOut); // pong is received, clear connection close timeout
        }
    }
})
```